# Pointer to Parent Class Member Method

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I am trying to get the following simple code to work:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Parent {
public:
    void method(int a) {
        std::cout << "Parent::method(" << a << ")" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    
};

template <typename T>
std::function<void()> test(T* v, void(T::* fn)(int)) {
    return std::function<void()>([v, fn](){
        v->fn(10);
    });
}

int main() {
    Child c;
    
    std::function<void()> fn = test(&c, &Child::method);
    
    fn();
    
    return 1;
}
```

But am getting the following error:

```
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('Child' and 'Parent')
  std::function<void()> fn = test(&c, &Child::method);
```

I get the same problem if I change my pointer to Parent::method. Since Child "is a" parent, why is the compiler unable to deduce this template?

Thanks!

Comment: The "dereference a pointer-to-member, `fn`, relative to a pointer to object, `v`" syntax is `v->*fn`, and you need parentheses when calling a member function: `(v->*fn)()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Child "is a" parent

It is in the object-oriented sense. But template argument deduction is primarily about type *identity*.

`&Child::method` names a member of `Parent`. It may be accessible in `Child` but it is declared in `Parent`. So the only available deduction of `T` from that member is `Parent`. On the other hand, the pointer deduces `T` to be `Child`. The *identity* of `T` here cannot be uniquely determined. So it's a deduction failure.

But we can still write your function template with a tweak:

```
template <class C, class P>
std::function<void()> test(C* v, void(P::* fn)(int)) {
    return std::function<void()>([v, fn](){
        (v->*fn)(10);
    });
}
```

Now the classes are deduced in their own context, without affecting the other. This can be enough as is (since `(v->*fn)(10)` will be ill-formed for unrelated classes). But additional checks may be put in-place to make the overload sfinae friendly.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `&Child::method` is a member function pointer to a method in `Parent`. The fact that `Child` can *access* this method is irrelevant as far as template argument deduction is concerned. The compiler sees that and deduces a `Parent` for the `T` parameter based on the first argument. At the same time, it deduces `Child` for `T` based on the first argument `&c`. This conflicts and you get an error.

You can get around this by putting the second argument of the function template in a non-deduced context

```
template <typename T>
struct I { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
std::function<void()> test(T* v, void(I<T>::type::* fn)(int)) {
                                   // ^________^  T here is not deduced
    return std::function<void()>([v, fn](){
        (v->*fn)(10);
    });
}
```

Now template argument deduction is unaffected, but you can still call `method` since it's accessible from the `Child` class.